# Google Calendar in iOS App Without WebView

Tags: iphone, ios, webview, google-calendar-api

Is it possible to display a Google Calendar in an iPhone app using a calendar-type view similar to that of the "Calendar" app instead of a WebView? What library do you recommend using to display the calendar? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never tried it, but you could check this framework out: https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary

It's got a `TKCalendarMonthView` class.